# Kivy toolbar malfunctioning

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to build a window that has several *'cards'* that contain certain information and some functional buttons using **kivymd**. What I am trying to do is add the *cards* to a **grid layout** and suspend that grid in a **floating layout**, but I'm having some issue with that look at the image attached. Also please suggest if a better way of doing this is possible.
Here's the code for the window. I'll later be making some functions to add more cards on pressing some button

```
<ProjectCard@MDGridLayout>
    md_bg_color: 0, 1, 1, 1
    cols: 1
    MDToolbar:
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: print(x)]]
        title: "Title"
        size_hint_y:0.3
    MDLabel:
        size_hint_y:0.1
        valign:"bottom"
        text:"mm:hh dd:mm:yy AM"
    MDLabel:
        size_hint_y:0.3
        multiline: True
        text:"john wick, richie rich, courage, garelt"
        valign:"top"
        adaptive_height: True
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:2
        size_hint_y:0.3
        MDLabel:
            text:"Status: " + "working"
        MDIconButton:
            icon:"details"
            adaptive_height: True




<ProjectsPage>
    FloatLayout
        MDGridLayout:
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            size_hint_x:0.95
            spacing:[10, 10]
            cols:1
            ProjectCard:
                size_hint_y:0.3
            ProjectCard:
                size_hint_y:0.3
            ProjectCard:
                size_hint_y:0.3
```

The image of kivy window
[image: Image of output]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add new Cards with button and you want to see all of them easily. So you can use ScrollView on your page. Also you can set this page's grid's cols as you want. I set this option to 2. I created these cards in .py file. You can make it in .kv too. I hope this codes help you to understand how to create new cards easily with action.
**main.py:**

```
#main.py:
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
class ProjectsPage(Screen):
    cards_grid = ObjectProperty()
    def add_card(self):
        card = Card()
        self.cards_grid.add_widget(card)
class Card(MDBoxLayout):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class my(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my().run()
```

**my.kv:**

```
<SM>:
    ProjectsPage:
<ProjectCard@MDGridLayout>
    size_hint_y:None
    height: '250sp'
    md_bg_color: 0, 1, 1, .5
    cols: 1
<ProjectsPage>:
    cards_grid:cards_grid
    BoxLayout:
        padding: '25sp','25sp','25sp','25sp'
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_y:.9
            do_scroll_x:False
            do_scroll_y:True
            GridLayout:
                id: cards_grid
                spacing: '25sp'
                size_hint_y:None
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols: 2
                Card:
                Card:
        Button:
            size_hint_y:.1
            text: 'Add New Card'
            on_release: root.add_card()
<Card>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    height: '250sp'
    md_bg_color: 0, 1, 1, .5
    MDToolbar:
        right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: print(x)]]
        title: "Title"
        size_hint_y:0.3
    MDLabel:
        size_hint_y:0.1
        valign:"bottom"
        text:"mm:hh dd:mm:yy AM"
    MDLabel:
        size_hint_y:0.3
        multiline: True
        text:"john wick, richie rich, courage, garelt"
        valign:"top"
        adaptive_height: True
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:2
        size_hint_y:0.3
        MDLabel:
            text:"Status: " + "working"
        MDIconButton:
            icon:"details"
            adaptive_height: True
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I Added a scroll view to the projectsPage. Did some tweaking and it is perfect now. My votes don't count but I'm telling you this was helpful